# Pick .csv file then import on .db

Tags: android, import, filechooser

I've seen some resources where importing file to .db but it's not a dynamic. How can I make my application that when I `choose any file` like .csv or .xls and then click on a button it is `import`-ed it in the `.db`?

Comment: http://www.researchgate.net/post/How_can_I_import_CSV_data_to_sqlite_database_and_retrieve_them_from_it_in_android

Answer (score 0):

sqlite have no api for import files. so you must read data from files and write SQL.
   csv file data format is very easy, but xls file is complicated。